# Addiong Scrollbar to Tkinter Entry or Text widgets

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter, widget

I am well aware that a scrollbar can be added to a Text widget. but my problem is i want it read only.The only way i can do is by making the state=DISABLED, but this will block my text, hence cant copy the text.
Well in the Tkinter Entry widget there is no yScroll behavior. Any idea how i can get these things worked? Any help is appreciated.

Right now i am using this for Text

`

```
root=Tk()   
 txt = Text(root, height=5, width=55)
 scr = Scrollbar(root)
 scr.config(command=txt.yview)
 txt.config(yscrollcommand=scr.set)
 txt.pack(side=LEFT)
 txt.insert(INSERT, "hello world\nhello world\n hello world\n hello world\n hello world\n     hello world\n hello world\n hello world\n hello world\n hello world\n")
 txt.insert(END,"\n")
 scr.pack(side="right", fill="y", expand=False)
 txt.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
 root.mainloop()
```

`

with this the problem is that the text can be edited.

Comment: Entry widgets have no yScroll behavior because they can only contain a single line.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I have found an alternative. you can find the code below 'root = tk.Tk()

t = tk.Text(root)
s = tk.Scrollbar(root, command=t.yview)

t.insert(tk.INSERT, "Read only. "*1000)
t.config(state=tk.DISABLED, yscrollcommand=s.set)

s.pack(side='right', fill='y')
t.pack()

root.mainloop()'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you can't seem to copy the text of a disabled widget is that the disabled widget on some platforms does not get focus, and focus is required to select text. You can rectify that by adding a binding to set the focus on a mouse click.

Add the following two lines to your code:

```
txt.configure(state="disabled")
txt.bind("<1>", lambda event: txt.focus_set())
```

Comment: Bingo! that is what i was looking for! Thanks Bryan. Also can i achieve something similar, i mean the y scroll with Tkinter Entry widget? It doesn't have a Y scroll behavior. Can i add the same?

Comment: `root = tk.Tk()

t = tk.Text(root)
s = tk.Scrollbar(root, command=t.yview)

t.insert(tk.INSERT, "Read only. "*1000)
t.config(state=tk.DISABLED, yscrollcommand=s.set)

s.pack(side='right', fill='y')
t.pack()

root.mainloop()`